# Citing many long URLs (shortening and numbering)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, counters, urls, biber

In my thesis I have to quote a lot from a single weblog. The URLs are mostly of this structure:

- `blogname.providername.com/stories/123456`
- `blogname.providername.com/stories/some-random-text-taken-from-the-first-words-of-the-blogpost`
- `blogname.providername.com/topics/some-topic`

or if it is a comment

- `blogname.providername.com/stories/123456/#123456`

I quote probably several dozen of these very long URLs mainly within one chapter, normally in the footnotes. The problem is that the footnotes get almost unreadable, bloated and hard to typeset properly (line breaks etc.). Because of that I thought of shortening them and citing them in an appendix (next to the bibliography).

The idea is to use something along the lines of “see URL-1, 2012-03-01” and in the next citation “see URL-2, 2010-07-20”, so they are numbered sequentially. 
And in the appendix there would be

> URL-1: blogname.providername.com/stories/123456
>
> URL-2: blogname.providername.com/stories/327162/#123456

The questions are:

- would it be useful to quote them via `bibtex`/`biblatex`-Database? Or is there a better way, because the list in the appendix should be separated from the ‘normal’ bibliography
- how to number them automatically as they are quoted?

For regular bibliography management I use `biblatex` and `biber`. I quote other URLs as well, so the bibliography driver for URLs shouldn’t be modified generally. BTW: the URLs have to be put into `\url{}`, because of hyperlinking them via hyperref and mainly because some of them include hash keys, which cause problems otherwise.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Any hints where and how to start would be welcome.

**Edit1**: Regarding jon’s hint: [This discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61681/switching-biblatex-styles-between-numeric-style-and-authortitle) might be showing the right direction, but I don’t get it to work yet. I tried using the following new definition of a numeric cite command.

> \newbibmacro*{numcite}{%
>   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
>    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
>      \printfield{labelnumber}%
>   }}
>
> \DeclareCiteCommand{\numcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
>   {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
>    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
>     \usebibmacro{numcite}}
>    {\multicitedelim}
>    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

But then I would still need a redefinition for my subbibliography. And I don’t know if that is possible.

**Edit2**: minimal working example (see my comment)

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}

@book{HorkheimerAdorno-DdA,
    Author = {Max Horkheimer and Theodor W. Adorno},
    Location = {Frankfurt am Main},
    Publisher = {Fischer Taschenbuch Verlag},
    Subtitle = {Philosophische Fragmente},
    Title = {Dialektik der Aufklärung},
    Year = {1988}}

@online{url-blog-example,
    Url = {http://blogname.provider.com/stories/some-random-text-from-the-beginning-of-the-blog-entry/#8360558},
    Keywords = {Blogurl},
    Year = {22.9.2010}}

@online{url-blog-another-example,
    Url = {http://blogname.provider.com/stories/some-more-but-different-random-text-from-the-beginning-of-the-blog-entry/#1239877},
    Keywords = {Blogurl},
    Year = {13.4.2004}}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage{hyperref,lipsum}


\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}


\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\footcite[34]{HorkheimerAdorno-DdA} \lipsum*[2]\footnote{Cf. \cite{url-blog-example} and cf. \cite{url-blog-another-example}.} 


\printbibheading
\printbibliography[notkeyword=Blogurl,heading=subbibliography,title={Main Sources}]
\printbibliography[keyword=Blogurl,heading=subbibliography,title={Blog Citations}]



\end{document}
```

Comment: A numeric citation/bibliography style would work well for this, I think.

Comment: Your appendix idea is possible, but I'd sooner suppress URLs in citations entirely and print them in the bibliography. Some details on your citation/bibliography style and sample `bib` file entries will probably help get this question answered.

Comment: @jon: I forgot to mention that I use authortitle-dw (a verbose style) as my main style for both citation and bibliography. But you’re right, what I want is a numeric style just for these special URL-citations. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Audrey: I do want to suppress the URLs in the citations as I tried to say in my description. In the text there is supposed to be only e.g. "URL-1" (verbatim) and the date. The URL itself should be printed in the list in the appendix. I’ve tried to give a minimal example with subdivided bibliography in my Edit. But without the redefinitions mentioned in my other comment to jon the citations in the footnotes are incomplete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example 18 from the biblatex documentation (`18-numeric-hybrid.tex`) will get you most of the way there. The document below takes the example a step further by integrating citation labels for URL references via the `shorthand` field, dispensing with the need for an additional citation command. The solution requires some fixes to the biber-only multiple sorting scheme feature available with biblatex 2.3+ and biber 1.3+.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-dw,
  labelnumber,defernumbers,alldates=iso8601]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

% adapted from authortitle-dw.cbx
\renewbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{shorthand}}%
  \ifkeyword{blog}
    {\iffieldundef{year}
       {}
       {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        \iffieldundef{urlyear}{\printdate}{\printurldate}}}
    {}%
  \global\booltrue{cbx:noidem}}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifkeyword{blog}
    {\edef\cbxlabelnumber{\thefield{prefixnumber}\thefield{labelnumber}}%
     \restorefield{shorthand}{\cbxlabelnumber}%
     \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifbool{cbx:fullcite}} or
       ( test {\ifbool{cbx:firstfull}} and not test {\ifciteseen} ) }
       {\clearfield{year}}
       {}%
     \DeclareFieldAlias{url}{blogurl}}
    {}}

\defbibenvironment{blog}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\clearfield{year}%
   \DeclareFieldAlias{url}{blogurl}%
   \let\finentrypunct\relax
   \item}

\DeclareFieldFormat{blogurl}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\addcolon}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{url1,
  Url = {http://blogname.provider.com/stories/entry/#8360558},
  Keywords = {blog},
  Year = {2010-09-22}}
@online{url2,
  Url = {http://blogname.provider.com/stories/text/#1239877},
  keywords = {blog},
  Year = {2004-04-13}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{markey,url2,companion,url1}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,
  title={Main References},notkeyword=blog,omitnumbers]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,
  title={Blog References},keyword=blog,env=blog,prefixnumbers={URL-},sorting=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Audrey, that was exactly what I needed (sorry for answering so late). Could you perhaps edit your entry and remove "labelnumber, " in the second bib-entry, because otherwise your example won't compile.

Comment: I've got one more question: how do I get a colon after the labels in the bibliography (e.g. URL1:). I tried to put an \addcolon after \printfield{labelnumber}}, but then something in the indentation gets wrong, if I use more than 10 entries.

Comment: You need to adjust the `labelnumberwidth` format. I'll make an edit to demonstrate.