# How to cite CTAN itself?

Tags: ctan

I'm writing about how Comprehensive Archive Networks with strong standards make languages more powerful and robust in a certain document to an audience that is unaware of them. I'd like to give an authoritative citation for CTAN (as well as CPAN and CRAN), but I'm having trouble locating anything that seems sufficiently formal.

What's the most formal citation you have for CTAN? (since the others are fairly off-topic)

To clarify, an example of a highly 'formal' citation would be a peer-reviewed journal article. A highly 'informal' citation would be a Facebook page with lots of 'likes'.

Comment: Give an example of your understanding of "formal citation".

Comment: For example you can use biblatex and use http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70299/citing-many-long-urls-shortening-and-numbering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's nothing specified.  when i write about my work on the archive, i would write one of
or either of those with the link

- CTAN
- Comprehensive TeX Archive

or either of those with the link [CTAN root](http://www.ctan.org/)